# Array Returning the same value in PHP

Tags: php

```
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT position
        FROM ".$this->table_name."
        WHERE c_name = '".$chName."'");

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
        {
            return(array($row['position']));
        }
```

I am getting the same value, even if i change the combox... i need the ID of the combox box when its changed. But for every time i select it displays the same value.

```
function getID($chName) {

}
```

chName is the value i am getting from combo box from Flex.

Answer (score 2):

You are always returning just the first row. Maybe you want the whole data set and not just the first record. So try this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT position
    FROM ".$this->table_name."
    WHERE c_name = '".$chName."'");
$retVal = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $retVal[] = $row['position']);
}
return $retVal;
```

Answer (score 0):

why

```
 return(array($row['position']));
```

and not just

```
return($row['position']);
```

For any other help you have to provide more informationn (hmtl? output?)

Answer (score 0):

Gumbo's answer is correct.

Notice that unconditionally returning something inside a loop makes the loop itself to be run **only once**.  This is true in general and you should always avoid such a monster :)

If you are a memory saver guy you do a very little memory an CPU improvement:

```
mysql_fetch_assoc()
```

that avoids retrieving an integer indexed array you'll not use

Answer (score 0):

Dont use double quotes if you arent wanting variables inside parsed.

```
$results = array();

// Dont forget you should be escaping $chName
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `position` FROM `{$this->table_name}` WHERE `c_name` = '$chName';");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    $results[] = $row['position'];
}

return $results;
```

Or

```
$results = array();

// Dont forget you should be escaping $chName
$result = mysql_query('SELECT `position` FROM `'.$this->table_name.'` WHERE `c_name` = \''.$chName.'\';');

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    $results[] = $row['position'];
}

return $results;
```

Answer (score 0):

The other folks have posted good answer; Just one suggestion - code a DB wrapper class so you don't have to manually fetch arrays all the time, which is a source of constant error. I have my own Query class and after performing a query, I just do $query->dumpResultAsArray() and do the for-each from there.

It's less efficient, but it's more robust and easier to debug.